# Copying Multiple Columns text from webpage and paste into Excel with formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to copy a table from a webpage and paste it in either google sheets or excel without loosing formatting. If I copy entire text and paste in excel then the data will appear in a single column one after one.
Link to webpage :
https://restaurant.store/product/all-purpose-handling-basket-11-ss/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXFr.png)

Please help

Comment: In *some* cases, holding down the Alt key while dragging with the mouse will let you select both columns and rows. There are also add-ins for browsers, such as *Print Edit WE* for *Firefox*, that make it easier to select text.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sir. But its not working as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a web page data scraping feature in excel that you can use.

[image]

Comment: The table is in div class format so can't copy paste in table format. I got this info from one of my friends.

Comment: Excel file is attached. Anybody can try to solve this problem through VBA programming??